# How to use Gauss-Bonnet theorem on a cube

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem for compact regular surfaces is often only enunciated for totally regular surfaces, with no singular points. But what if I wanted to state it on a surface with a finite number of singular points but otherwise regular, like a cube? How is the Gauss-Bonnet modified? I know somehow the curvature has to be concentrated on the vertices, but I'd like some help in making that notion precise. 
Thank you.

Comment: You might start by looking at Exercise 13 on pp. 90-91 of my differential geometry text (linked in my profile). Think about the area subtended by the Gauss map. In the case of a cube, you'll get a solid angle of $4\pi/8$ at each vertex, and so the sum of those solid angles will give you $2\pi\chi(M)$.